# How to implement security in WCF service so that only selected client can access my service (without checking userid/passwork in each method)?

Tags: wcf, security, header, message, idispatchmessageinspector

I have implemented `IDispatchMessageInspector` in my WCF service to provide security as given bellow.

**Client side code:**

```
 private class mySecurityInspector : IClientMessageInspector, IDispatchMessageInspector
  {
   private const string HEADER_NS = "urn:myservice:authentication-header:2011";

   public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
   {
     MessageHeader<string> messageHeader = new MessageHeader<string>  
                              (getAuthKeyFromConfig(), false, string.Empty, false);

    // add the new header to our request
     request.Headers.Add(messageHeader.GetUntypedHeader("",                   
                                                   HEADER_NS));
      return null;
    }
```

}

**Server Side(Service):**

```
 private class mySecurityInspector: IDispatchMessageInspector
 {
   private const string HEADER_NS = "urn:myservice:authentication-header:2011";

  public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request,     
      System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext            
               instanceContext)
     {

            string authKey = request.Headers.GetHeader<string>(“”, HEADER_NS);
             if (authKey != getAuthKeyFromConfig())
            {
               throw new 
              Exception(string.Format(ServiceMessages.MSG_UNAUTHORISED_CLIENT,  
             "");
   }
```

}

}

This way client who know the authkey only can access my service. this is what I have done. but I'm not sure about security as I think if somehow some one hack 
this authkey from soap headed on the network wire will able to access my service. How to protect my service in this scenario? please provide me a solution so that only selected client can access my service.

Answer (score 1):

The solution in your scenario is HTTPS. You are afraid that somebody can stole authkey on the wire = you need to have secure channel and the simplest (and in your case the best) way to get secure channel is to use HTTPS.

I'm not sure why you mentioned password / userid in question's title but if you use this authentication header only for successfully authenticated clients you are most probably reinventing the wheel. WCF already support this scenario. It is called SecurityContext (or security session) and it is for example used by `WSHttpBinding` with `Message` security model and `UserName` client credentials type - credentials are validated only with the first request and after that clients sends security token which is valid for the whole duration of the session. The disadvantage is that it makes your communication statefull.

Comment: thanks Ladislav.. if i use WSHttpBinding, would classic ASP  application will be able to consume my service? i am not sure, so i have used basicHttpBinding. I'm not sure why you mentioned password / userid in question's title : reason is that i want client application automatically will pickup authkey from config file or from any other persistent layer and service will validate it and will take action accordingly.>>>

Comment: No. If you need to call the service from classic ASP you should not use WSHttpBinding. As I understand your authkey it is the same as username and password. You developed custom solution to replace username password facility which is built-in and works in exactly same way.